# Radio Button with Multiple Values Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, form-for

I want to have multiple values saved when a radio button is selected. I tried to do this with a hidden_field but it did not work.

```
<%= form_for @checkin do |f| %>
    <% @api["results"][0..9].each do |n| %>
      <%= f.label :name, n["name"] %>
      <%= f.radio_button(:name, n["name"]) %></br>
      <%= f.hidden_field :placeid, :value => n["place_id"] %>
    <%end%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

I am looping through a Google maps api json response and would like to save the name and place_id when a radio button is selected and submitted. Right now only the name saves correctly.

Here is the controller where I am creating a new Checkin with the checkin_params

```
class CheckinsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @checkins = Checkin.all
end

def create
    @checkin = Checkin.new(checkin_params)
    if @checkin.save
        redirect_to @checkin
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @checkin = Checkin.find(params[:id])
end

private

def checkin_params
    params.require(:checkin).permit(:name, :placeid)
end
```

end

And here is the Searches Controller where I get the @api from

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

def new 
    @search = Search.new 
end

def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
    @search.ip_address = "50.172.64.130"
    if @search.save
        redirect_to @search
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show 
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    response = Search.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=#{@search.latitude},#{@search.longitude}&keyword=#{@search.keyword}&types=&rankby=distance&key=AIzaSyAny_eoq9b1UGL7Ow20vDTet9yIBb60BwA")
    @api = response.parsed_response
    @checkin = Checkin.new
end

private

def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:keyword)
end
```

end

Any tips on my existing idea or a suggestion for another way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why not move this logic to controller?

Comment: Save the id manually in the controller.

Comment: I want the user to be able to pick which location they have "Checked in" The form right now lists 10 locations with radio buttons so they can pick one to checkin.

Comment: You've only showed the code for the form, which will pass the parameter through to the controller. What have you done with that parameter?

Comment: @margo I added some edits with the controllers. I use the parameters from the form to create a new Checkin. Thanks again for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the placeId is getting passed to the form hidden field as you expect it to? Have you defined the attribute placeid on the checkin model? Look in the terminal logs to see what is happening when you post the form.